# Obtener el numero de etiquetas en un <li> javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo varias etiquetas, en este ejemplo pongo 2 que tienen varias etiquetas.
Lo que deseo es que en la lista ul,obtener todos lo `<li>` y buscar si ese `<li>` tiene dos iconos  `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` , si llegara a tener dos , no hago nada, pero si tuviera 1, agregar un  `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` para que sean dos, `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>`,ahora hay varios `<li>` ,no tengo una cantidad exacta.

```
          <ul id="lista_vista">         
            <li class="replies">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <p>Hola
                <span class="hora">8:15 <i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                </p>                    
            </li>
            <li class="sent">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <p>Nuevo.                                               
                  <span class="hora">8:15 <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> 
                </p>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

Lo estoy haciendo con javascript, o jquery, lo intente y obtener las etiquetas pero no me da la cantidad de iconos, como podria hacer?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer todos los `li` y buscar los `i` con `find()`.  Si la cantidad es igual a 1, agregas un icono mas.  Algo asi:

```js
$("li").each(function(i, li) {
  var icons = $(li).find("i");
  if (icons.length == 1) {
    icons.after('<i class="fa fa-check">');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul id="lista_vista">         
            <li class="replies">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <p>Hola
                <span class="hora">8:15 <i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                </p>                    
            </li>
            <li class="sent">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <p>Nuevo.                                               
                  <span class="hora">8:15 <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span> 
                </p>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo!

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery es muy sencillo, si aplicas a este code te da cuantos iconos tiene

```
$(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){// por cada li
    let icons = $(this).find('i')//buscamos los i, puedes usar cualquier selector
    if (icons.length >= 2) {//los contamos
        //no haces nada
    } else {
        //agregas un icono más
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Gracias por respuesta, me ayudo a verlo de manera diferente, me ayudo en resolverlo, Mil Gracias!